# Google app engine multiple languages

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

In google app engine, is it possible to write an app in two different languages, e.g. python and PHP. I am very new to Google app engine, and am not sure how to go about it. If it is possible will it incur any charges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/). Each module can be a different language.

You will only be charged if you go over the free quotas - i.e. there is no charge to use the modules feature outside of the standard usage based charges.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by creating two separate modules one contain python code and another one contain php code.. It's working when it got redirected to `.py` file but for `.php` file, page is empty but I get a 200 response without any error codes.

Comment: with this command, I initiated the local server `dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app.yaml php.yaml static_backend.yaml --php_executable_path /usr/bin/php`

Comment: asked a question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716279/app-engine-modules-not-working