# Connecting different microservices to same cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to have 2 different applications (one written in Python and one in Java) in the same App Engine environment (Standard) and have them ***view the same `Datastore`***?

From my understanding, ***`Google Cloud Datastore`*** is the storage option that comes along with any AppEngine application, but *also* exists as an external service any application can use.

Is there a way for one application to view the other application's "embedded" ***`Datastore`*** (without one application exposing an API to it)? If not, how can 2 different applications ***use the same storage***? I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding ***`Cloud Datastore`*** urls or using them as a third party database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google app engine multiple languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588006/google-app-engine-multiple-languages)

Comment: Actually not even close

Comment: Why is Jeff's suggestion not close? You can develop apps in different languages and just differentiate your `yaml` files with `runtime: java` and `runtime: python`. Am I wrong? That is what the question pointed by Jeff is about, from what I could understand...

Comment: Additionally, check these docs: Configuring your App with app.yaml in [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) and in [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml). Each AppEngine project has only one Datastore instance, as I understand. Any app deployed in a given project, regardless of the language, should access the project Datastore instance without a problem.

Comment: The possible duplicate addresses the question of having apps in different languages in the same app engine project. Mine is relative to different apps viewing the same `Datastore`. Also configuring the app with `app.yaml` is for `flexible` app engine installations only whereas I'm pointing out that I'm working on `Standard` App engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can use the REST API version https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis. The real question is, why do you need to 2 different apps here? Micro service is usually implemented in appengine using module on a single app, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine.

Comment: Can I have modules written in different languages?

Comment: According to the question comment link they can.